# Delete Devise user (No route matches [DELETE] "users/edit.8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I do not understand how my rails application not find the path Edit_user_registration_path(usr)  when it is in the command output "rake routes".

THE routes.rb

```
  resources :comentarios
  resources :productos
  resources :seudonimos
  resources :configuraciones
  resources :sociales
  resources :clientespotenciales do
      member do
          get :confirmarsi
          get :confirmarno
          get :confirmarbaja
          get :conocidos
      end
      collection do
        get :altaunete
        get :altaconocidos
        get :confirmaunete
        get :confirmacion
      end
  end
  get 'unete',           to: 'clientespotenciales#new',           as: 'unete'
  get 'altaunete',       to: 'clientespotenciales#altaunete',     as: 'altaunete'
  get 'confirmaunete',   to: 'clientespotenciales#confirmaunete', as: 'confirmaunete'
  get 'confirmarcorreo', to: 'clientespotenciales#confirmacion',  as: 'confirmacorreo'
  resources :clipotcategorias 
  resources :usuarios do
    member do
        get :seudonimos, format: :json
    end
  end
  get 'textos/lista'
  resources :textos do
      member do
          get :leer
      end
  end
  resources :categoriastextos
  concern :the_role, TheRole::AdminRoutes.new
  namespace :admin do
    concerns :the_role
  end
  get 'web/index'
  get 'web/admin'
  get 'web/contacto'
  get 'web/contactopublicidad'
  get 'web/privacidad'
  get 'web/avisocookies'
  get 'web/avisolegal'
  get 'web/contratoescritores'
  get 'web/configuracion'
  get 'web/textocontratoescritores'
  get 'web/faq'
  post  'contactopublicidad',      to: 'web#contactopublicidad', as: 'contactopublicidad'
  resources :web do
      member do
          get :setescritor
          get :setlector
          delete :borrarusuario
      end
  end
  devise_for :users
```

**THE LOG**

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/edit.8"):

**THE LINK IN THE VIEW**

**THE DEVISE THE ROUTES** Note: No more routes form user i the rake routes display

```
             new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                  devise/sessions#new
                 user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                  devise/sessions#create
         destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                                 devise/sessions#destroy
                user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#create
            new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                             devise/passwords#new
           edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                            devise/passwords#edit
                              PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#update
                              PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                 devise/passwords#update
     cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#cancel
            user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#create
        new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                  devise/registrations#new
       edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#edit
                              PATCH  /users(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#update
                              PUT    /users(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#update
                              DELETE /users(.:format)                                          devise/registrations#destroy
            user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)                             devise/confirmations#create
        new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                         devise/confirmations#new
                              GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)                             devise/confirmations#show
                         root GET    /                                                         web#index
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link_to specifies `edit_user_registration_path(usr)`. Try  `user_registration_path(usr)`.

The former will DELETE `users/edit.8`, which isn't a path in your route file above. You only have one DELETE path (`users/8`)